# How to draw a column chart with one single field and multiple colors using google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Here is my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SNJr/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
function drawColumnChart(container, data) {    
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
    var options = {fontSize: 16};
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
    drawColumnChart($("#satisfactionBarGraph")[0], [
        ['satisfaction', 'percent'],
        ['大変満足',          10      ],
        ['満足',            22      ],
        ['やや満足',          30      ],
        ['やや不満',          10      ],
        ['不満',            5       ]
    ]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="satisfactionBarGraph" style="width: 524px; height: 370px;" class="chartContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what I really want: [image]

I have two problems:

(1) I want the text below the x-axis to align top bottom
I have run through the [document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) but cannot find the option 
(2) I want the columns to be in different colors
Because I have only one filed, so all of them are in the same color. I'm wondering whether I used the right chart.

And suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks a lot for all your answers. I combined your solutions and finally figured it out:

[final result](http://jsfiddle.net/2SNJr/32/)

Hope this can help anyone who meets the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The Google Visualization API's ColumnCharts color data by series, so if you want multiple colors for your bars, you have to split them into different series.
    function drawColumnChart(container, data) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

```
    var columns = [0];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        columns.push({
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
            calc: (function (x) {
                return function (dt, row) {
                    return (row == x) ? dt.getValue(row, 1) : null;
                }
            })(i)
        });
    }
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(columns);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
    var options = {
        fontSize: 16,
        // set the "isStacked" option to true to make the column spacing work
        isStacked: true
    };
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
// use the callback from the google loader to draw the chart rather than document ready
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: function () {
    drawColumnChart($("#satisfactionBarGraph")[0], [
        ['satisfaction', 'percent'],
        ['大変満足', 10],
        ['満足', 22],
        ['やや満足', 30],
        ['やや不満', 10],
        ['不満', 5]
    ]);
}});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Rrhak/

I don't think the Visualization API supports vertical writing like that.  You can rotate text to be aligned vertically, but that's not what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: The drawback here is 5 legends - or no legend. But this is the "sane" way, I guess - saw you helped a lot by that in the google forums! :) +1 ...How do you force certain colors for each bar?

Comment: You can set the `colors` option to set the colors, or you can set the `series.<series index.color` option to set the color for each series individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can get vertical labels like you want with a little bit of finagling.

I put a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2SNJr/29/):

> [image: Results Image]

I hope this answer makes you 大変満足.

## Add Spaces

Your data needs to have each character with a space between it so that they can be broken up in to separate lines:

```
    ['satisfaction', 'percent'],
    ['大 変 満 足',       10      ],
    ['満 足',           22      ],
    ['や や 満 足',       30      ],
    ['や や 不 満',       10      ],
    ['不 満',           5       ]
```

## Change Axis Display Values

For the `hAxis` you need to set the following options:

```
maxTextLines: 5,
slantedText: false,
showTextEvery: 1,
minTextSpacing: 40,
maxAlternation: 1
```

`maxTextLines` will allow your labels to be broken up in to multiple vertical lines. 4 would likely work as well as 5 here, since you only have 4 characters.

`slantedText` ends up being used over splitting up over multiple lines for some reason. So I turned it off manually.

`showTextEvery` prevents it from showing horizontal labels on one line by only display a subset of your axis labels.

`minTextSpacing` ensures that even though your lines are one character wide, the chart is fooled in to thinking that it needs to add line breaks.

`maxAlternation` prevents you from having two 'levels' of labels so that they all line up flush with the axis.

## Adjust the Height of the Chart

If you leave the chart height as default, there is only space for 2 lines of labels, so you end up with labels that say

```
や
や
…
```

To prevent that, you need to artificially increase the height of the chart. There are a dozen ways to do this, I just set the `height` property manually.

Comment: vote +1:)  smart trick, thanks a lot for your detail explanation and this really makes me 大変満足 :)

Comment: Japanese and Google Visualization? I'm all over it. I hope that this works out for you when combined with your other trick.